# Update object property in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to represent my objects. Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'label' | filter:query | orderBy: 'label'">
  <h1>{{item.label}}</h1>
  <h1>{{item.property}}</h1>
</div>
```

Also I'm using socket.io. So, when property of one of the objects is updated, my back-end will send socket.io event with this object and i will catch it in my AngularJS Ctrl.

```
  socket.on('itemPropertyUpdated', function(item){
      // Update property of this item in ng-repeat
    });
```

My question is:
How i can update property of one of the objects represented in ng-repeat ?
I mean, how i can update `<h1>{{item.property}}</h1>` without reloading all `items` array.

(The property of the objects will updated with frequency because it is the "state (on/off)" of each object.)

Comment: *"How i can update property of one of the objects in ng-repeat?"*. Not clear what you are asking. Clarify.

Comment: If you are working within the angular world. An array should 'update' itself. Otherwise you have to kick the angular cycle manually. The latter indicates that there is some code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Events outside of AngularJS need to have an $apply. This tells angular to apply a digest cycle to update the view.

```
socket.on('itemPropertyUpdated', function(item){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      // Update property of this item in ng-repeat
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the scope:

```
  socket.on('itemPropertyUpdated', function(item){
      // Update property of this item in ng-repeat
      someObject.someProperty = someValue;
      scope.$evalAsync();
    });
```

If you don't, you can call `angular.element(someDomElement).scope()` to get it.